# Django Rest Framework view returns an empty object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a REST API to serve an Android application.  I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, so I am attempting to use the django-friendship application found at https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/ in conjunction with DRF.  Unfortunately, the documentation for django-friendship is rather sparse and I am new to Django/DRF development.  I am running into an issue where I cannot view the friend relationship based on an individual.

The friend list view should display all of the requesting user's friends.  I am able to create friends on a separate view, but that view shows EVERY friend relationship.  I want to be able to view the friends of a specific user.  That is, when a user GETs the /friends/ directory it will display their friend list.

However, right now this view only displays an empty JSON object, rather than the friend list for the user.  How should I change my FriendList view so that it will properly return the friends list for the user?

views.py

```
class FriendList(APIView):
    """
    Lists all of the requesting users friends
    """
    def get(self, request):
        friends = Friend.objects.friends(request.user)
        serializer = FriendSerializer(friends, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer.py

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Friend
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                               namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^friends', views.FriendList.as_view())
```

Comment: Two possible issues: You aren't telling DRF what fields to use (which would explain an empty `{}`) and `friends` might be empty (which would explain an empty `[]`). What does your response actually include?

Comment: The response includes to_user (requesting user), from_user (their friend) and created (time they became friends).  I have been testing it with two different usernames.  I set them as friends with one another.  If I try and go to the /friends/ url with a user that doesn't have any friends, I get an error.

However, if I go to /friends/ logged in as a user who does have friends, I do not get an error but rather an empty array.

Comment: "I get an error" might be useful to include the error in your question, it might have a hint as to why the other response includes no objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(self, request):        
  friends = Friend.objects.friends(request.user)
```

In the above code you may want to use `get()` or `filter()` instead of `friends()`